# How to download to a file location and find the full path to location

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, aws-cli

I am trying to download all the files in an s3 bucket to another s3 bucket

I can upload to my s3 bucket already, but I can't figure out how to download it so that I know the full file location, (*this won't be done on my computer* so I don't know the first few file paths)

I am using **python**, **boto3**, and have been looking at using `subprocess.run([])` possibly so that I can use the AWS CLI
but would prefer boto3 since that is messy

(I have to download it)
because I have to put stuff in DynamoDB

Comment: Is there some reason [download_file](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.download_file) won't work?

Comment: Can you share the commands you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

This is an example from boto [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-example-download-file.html):

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
with open('path_to_your_file', 'wb') as f:
    s3.download_fileobj('BUCKET_NAME', 'OBJECT_NAME', f)
```

You have full control when you can download it. `path_to_your_file`

If you don't know where to download it for you can always use python [tmpfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) that will find you a proper temporary writable folder/file.

for example: `tempfile.TemporaryFile()`